# $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ be non-constant polynomial , $n>1$ , the function $A \to p(A)$ is surjective on $M(n, \mathbb C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial and $n>1$  , then is it true that the function

$f:M(n,\mathbb C) \to M(n, \mathbb C)$ defined as $f(A)=p(A) , \forall A \in M(n, \mathbb C)$ is surjective ?

( I only know that the function is not surjective on $M(n,\mathbb R)$ when degree of $p(x)$ is even , but I don't know when we allow complex matrices )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. Consider the matrix.$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
It is not the square of a complex matrix, so $p(X)=X^2$ is not surjective.

Comment: But what if $p$ is another polynomial?