# $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ be a polynomial of odd degree , $n>1$ be an integer , then is the function $A \to p(A)$ surjective on $M(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ be a polynomial of odd degree , $n>1$ be an integer , then is the function

$f: M(n,\mathbb R) \to M(n, \mathbb R)$ defined as $f(A)=p(A) , \forall A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ surjective ?

This is related [$p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ be non-constant polynomial , $n>1$ , the function $A \to p(A)$ is surjective on $M(n, \mathbb C)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841469/px-in-mathbb-rx-be-non-constant-polynomial-n1-the-function-a-to)

Comment: The counter-example in the other question works just as well for $p(X)=X^3$...

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the linked question still applies. Consider the matrix
\begin{align*}
y &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 &  0\\
\vdots & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\in M_n(\mathbb{R}).
\end{align*}
If $y = x^n$ for some $x\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, then all the eigenvalues of $x$ must vanish. Since $x$ satisfies its own characteristic equation, $x = 0$.